# Space of analytic function and sequence space $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D} = \{z:|z|<1\}$ be open unit disc in complex plane. Define space of analytic function: 
$N^p=\{f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C} | f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^p < \infty\}$. 
For $p=1$ we have Wiener algebra, and for $p=2$ we have Hardy space $H^2$. What we know about this space of analytic function for $p \in (1,2) \cup (2,\infty]$. Where can I find some books for this spaces?

Comment: The multiplier algebras of these spaces were studied in [On lp -multipliers of functions analytic in the disk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5384) and references 1-6 therein.